# Convert MySQL functions POSITION and SUBSTR from JavaScript functions indexOf and charAt

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'd like to transform a JavaScript function to a MySQL one.

The JavaScript code is like:

```
var set1 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var set2 = "ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var setpari = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var setdisp = "BAKPLCQDREVOSFTGUHMINJWZYX";
var s = 0;

for( i = 1; i <= 13; i += 2 )
    s += setpari.indexOf( set2.charAt( set1.indexOf( cf.charAt(i) )));
for( i = 0; i <= 14; i += 2 )
    s += setdisp.indexOf( set2.charAt( set1.indexOf( cf.charAt(i) )));
```

So, I've "translated" it to:

```
SET set1 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
SET set2 = "ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
SET setpari = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
SET setdisp = "BAKPLCQDREVOSFTGUHMINJWZYX";
SET s=0;

SET v_counter = 0;
WHILE v_counter < 14
DO
    SET set1IndexOf = POSITION(SUBSTR(codFisc, v_counter+1, 1) IN set1);
    SET s = s + POSITION(SUBSTR(set2, set1IndexOf, 1) IN setpari) -1;
    SET v_counter=v_counter+2;
END WHILE;

SET v_counter = 0;
WHILE v_counter < 15
DO
    SET set1IndexOf = POSITION(SUBSTR(codFisc, v_counter+1, 1) IN set1);
    SET s = s + POSITION(SUBSTR(set2, set1IndexOf, 1) IN setdisp) -1;
    SET v_counter=v_counter+2;
END WHILE;
```

But the MySQL function returns a wrong result.

I know that `charAt` and `indexOf` are zero-based indexes, while `SUBSTR` and `POSITION` are one-based indexes. So I've incremented the `v_counter` but it is still wrong.
I can't see any difference between the two codes, but there's a bug somewhere.

Anyone can help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post expected result and actual result?

Comment: Assuming `setpari`, `setdisp` and `set1` are not arrays, have you tried using `INSTR() ` instead

Comment: @Fran sorry, I've added the variables initialization part. Thanks

Comment: @Vasan With cf (or codFisc) equals to "MGLLSN83C13F205S" javascript returns 122, MySQL 139.

Comment: what is cf in the javascript code?

Comment: Your first JS loop starts with 1 and will access cf.charAt(1), which is actually the 2nd character. 
Your first MySQL loop accesses SUBSTR(...,1,1) which is actually the first character (since SUBSTR is 1-based).

Comment: @RaymondNijland cf is the user input, for example, when it is "MGLLSN83C13F205S" javascript returns 122 (right) and MySQL 139 (wrong). Thanks

Comment: @Vasan I had not noticed that difference... That's the problem. Thanks.